# How to : required validator based on user role ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

i have a form where i have the field "Real Cost" i want to customize its appearance and wither it should be validated based on user role.

to be more clear is say the client want to show his field in the form or details page and also make it editable for users in Roles "Senior Sales, Manager" but not other roles, so can anyone please guide me of the best way ?

should i write custom required validation based on user in role, and if so can you please provide the right implementation of it?

some may tell me create custom model for this, but i think it would be hassle plus the Roles will be dynamic so it is not predefined set of roles.

i hope i was clear enough

Answer (score 1):

Security is definitely something that should be happening in the model or the controller but never in the View -- that is well beyond the View's scope of concern. Which is to display the data that the controller gives it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Wyatt you need to make all these decisions at the model level and then populate a 'View Model' with all the answers, which then can be used in the view to improve user experience.

In the ViewModel for this form, have a property IsRealCostEditable, which will be set by your service/model layer by checking the user's role.  Now you can easily adjust the UI for that field.

Answer (score 1):

You can create duplicate pages and one page can contain the view model which doesn't changes anything in the page... AND you can have an EDIT button which redirects to the editable page.
Make that page protected with authentication. SO you will asked to authenticate as your role before you can edit it

OTHERWISE.. there is no way your ViewModel can make decisions, its on the  Service Layer.